# How to get nearest neighbor of object point that have point_id using tree of Spatial.kdTree

Tags: python, python-2.7, kdtree, spatial-index

Help me. I'm stuck. I have a `class` of `point`. The attributes of that class are `lat`, `Long`, `point_id`, `name`. There some points that has same `Lat`, and `Long`. So, i need `point_id` as points identity. Actually, I want to get nearest neighbor of my point using tree of `kdTree`. I have no problem when I construct `kdTree`, but when I want to know my point nearest neighbor, the result is list `(Lat,Long)` of nearest neighbor whereas I want `point_id` as my result because there are some points have same `Lat`, and `Long`.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
import psycopg2
import math
import psycopg2.extensions   

class Point:
def __init__(self, id_point, name, Lat, Long):
    self.id_point=id_point
    self.name=name
    self.Lat=Lat
    self.Long=Long

def Struktur_KdTree(points):
    tree= spatial.KDTree(points)
    return tree

def getNearestPoint(tree,point,radius):
    return tree.query_ball_point(point,radius)

try:
   conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='Chicago_crime' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='1234'")
except :
    print "I'm unable to connect to the database"

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""SELECT id_objek, primary_descript, lat, long from data_crime""")

data = []
Lat = []
Long = []
for id_jenis, jenis, lat, long in cur.fetchall():
     data.append(Point(id_point,name,Lat,Long))
     Lat.append(lat)
     Long.append(long)

dataPoints = zip (Lat,Long)

tree = Struktur_KdTree(dataPoints)
result=[]
radius=2
for point in dataPoint:
   result.append(getNearestPoint(tree,point,radius))
```

Please give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Use a dict (or [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) to record a mapping from `(lat, lng)` tuples to lists of `Points`.
Armed with this dict (let's call it `pointmap`), given a `(lat, lng)` you will
be able to look up all the `Points` at that location.

```
pointmap = collections.defaultdict(list)
locations = set()
for id_jenis, jenis, lat, lng in np.random.randint(10, size=(N, 4)):
    point = Point(id_jenis, jenis, lat, lng)
    pointmap[lat, lng].append(point)
```

The keys in the `pointmap` dict are `(lat, lng)` tuples which we can form into a NumPy array to be passed to `spatial.KDTree`:

```
locations = np.array(pointmap.keys())
tree = spatial.KDTree(locations)
```

Now, we can iterate through each location and find
the nearest points:

```
for loc in locations:
    indices = getNearestPoint(tree, loc, radius)
```

Note that `query_ball_point` returns a list of indices (that index into
`locations`). The actual locations are given by `locations[indices]`. Here we're
taking advantage of NumPy fancy indexing -- made possible because `locations` is
a NumPy array.

For each location in `location[indices]`, we can now obtain a list of `Points` by looking up the associated point using our dict, `pointmap`:

```
near_points = [point for near_loc in locations[indices]
               for point in pointmap[tuple(near_loc)]]
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import spatial
import collections

class Point:

    def __init__(self, id_point, name, Lat, Long):
        self.id_point = id_point
        self.name = name
        self.Lat = Lat
        self.Long = Long

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point({}, {}, {}, {})'.format(
            self.id_point, self.name, self.Lat, self.Long)

def getNearestPoint(tree, point, radius):
    return tree.query_ball_point(point, radius)

pointmap = collections.defaultdict(list)

N = 10
for id_jenis, jenis, lat, lng in np.random.randint(10, size=(N, 4)):
    point = Point(id_jenis, jenis, lat, lng)
    pointmap[lat, lng].append(point)

locations = np.array(pointmap.keys())
tree = spatial.KDTree(locations)

result = []
radius = 2

for loc in locations:
    indices = getNearestPoint(tree, loc, radius)
    near_points = [point for near_loc in locations[indices]
                   for point in pointmap[tuple(near_loc)]]
    print('{} close to {}'.format(loc, near_points))
```

yields output like:

```
[8 3] close to [Point(2, 9, 8, 3)]
[7 1] close to [Point(8, 6, 7, 1), Point(2, 1, 6, 1)]
[4 5] close to [Point(7, 1, 4, 5), Point(4, 9, 3, 6)]
[6 1] close to [Point(8, 6, 7, 1), Point(2, 1, 6, 1)]
[2 0] close to [Point(0, 1, 2, 0), Point(4, 3, 4, 0)]
[3 6] close to [Point(7, 1, 4, 5), Point(4, 9, 3, 6)]
[7 9] close to [Point(1, 9, 7, 9)]
[9 6] close to [Point(8, 5, 9, 6)]
[2 4] close to [Point(4, 4, 2, 4)]
[4 0] close to [Point(0, 1, 2, 0), Point(4, 3, 4, 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you @unutbu . But I get error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/s2/semester 3/tesis/phyton/Kdtree2.py", line 35, in <module>
    tree = spatial.KDTree(locations)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\kdtree.py", line 229, in __init__
    self.n, self.m = np.shape(self.data)
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`

Comment: My mistake. When converting a set to a NumPy array, you must convert the set to a tuple or list first: `locations = np.array(list(locations))`.

Comment: Thank you for your best solution and detail explanation. You save me 